# Detecting user name from process ID

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Ho can i get user account name, that ran the process with specified id. Is there any api function for this?

I am using windows,c++.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is not an API function that does this directly, however you can combine a few API calls to do this. Of course your program will need to satisfy any ACLs that are applied to the process that you are interested in examining.

First, given the process ID, you'll need to open a handle to the process. You can use [`OpenProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320%28VS.85%29.aspx) for that, requesting the `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` access right.

Once you have that handle, you can call [`OpenProcessToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379295%28VS.85%29.aspx), requesting the `TOKEN_QUERY` access right.

Finally, you can then call [`GetTokenInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446671%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), requesting the `TokenUser` information class, which will give you the user account of the token. This information is provided to you in the form of a `SID`. To convert the `SID` to the actual name of the account, you can call [`LookupAccountSid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379166%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Don't forget to call [`CloseHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724211%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on both the process handle and the token handle once you're finished with them.

Answer (score 1):

And this is function using Aaron Klotz algorithm:

```
public static string GetProcessOwnerByID(int processId)
{
  IntPtr processHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
  IntPtr tokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
  try
  {
    processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, false, processId);
    if (processHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
      return "NO ACCESS";

    OpenProcessToken(processHandle, TOKEN_QUERY, out tokenHandle);
    using (WindowsIdentity wi = new WindowsIdentity(tokenHandle))
    {
      string user = wi.Name;
      return user.Contains(@"\") ? user.Substring(user.IndexOf(@"\") + 1) : user;
    }
  }
  finally
  {
    if (tokenHandle != IntPtr.Zero) CloseHandle(tokenHandle);
    if (processHandle != IntPtr.Zero) CloseHandle(processHandle);
  }
}
```

Whole function (with constants) can be found on [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/MPrtenjak/efe606738c5bf09d59f06417e1ed024a)