# Run a Windows App using a specific User account

Tags: c#, windows, exe, application-settings

I need to ensure that my widnows app (winform not console) runs under a certain user account (in other words any user can be logged on to the maching but the .exe will always execute as the specified user).

Can this be done programtically? If so, how?

Comment: How do you intent to authenticate as the user? Will you store the password somewhere?

Comment: Yes I can have the pwd stored somewhere where the app can access it. Or hard code it if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start the application like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(myPath);
psi.UserName = username;

SecureString ss = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in password)
{
 ss.AppendChar(c);
}

psi.Password = ss;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start(psi);
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do in your app is check if you're running as the desired user, and if not, create a new instance of your app as that other user. The first instance would then exit.

To check which user you are running as, you could adapt the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172392/detecting-user-name-from-process-id/3172404#3172404) so that the process queries itself for its token information.

Use [`CreateProcessWithLogonW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), passing the `LOGON_WITH_PROFILE` login flag. The user you are logging in as must have the appropriate policies set to be allowed to log on interactively.

EDIT: Now that you have indicated that you are using .NET, here's how you should do it:

First you need to find out which user you are currently running as. Use the [`WindowsIdentity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e599ywa6.aspx) class from the `System.Security.Principal` namespace. Call its [`GetCurrent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.getcurrent.aspx) method to obtain the `WindowsIdentity` object for the user that you are running as. The [`Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.name.aspx) property will give you the actual user name that you are running under.

In your [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) object, set `LoadUserProfile = true`, the `FileName` field, possibly the `Arguments` field, the `UserName` and `Password` fields, possibly the `Domain` field, and set `UseShellExecute = false`. Then call [`Process.Start()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx), passing in your `ProcessStartInfo` object.

Here's a sample that I threw together, but I don't have a C# compiler installed to test it:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Principal;

// Suppose I need to run as user "foo" with password "bar"

class TestApp
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        string userName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        if( !userName.Equals( "foo" ) ) {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = "testapp.exe";
            startInfo.UserName = "foo";

            SecureString password = new SecureString();
            password.AppendChar( 'b' );
            password.AppendChar( 'a' );
            password.AppendChar( 'r' );
            startInfo.Password = password;

            startInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            Process.Start( startInfo );    
            return;
        }
        // If we make it here then we're running as "foo"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the links. I am using C# but will look at the solutions suggested in detail in the morning.

Comment: Please see my edits, I have added some content relevant to .NET.