# How to get username of process running in task manager?

Tags: c#, windows, taskmanager

I want to know the user that created each process.

How do I get the usernames of all the processes running in task manager using c#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into [Win32_Process Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372(VS.85).aspx), and [GetOwner Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390460(VS.85).aspx)

[Sample Code](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/10/wmi-made-easy-for-c/)

[Sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777548/how-do-i-determine-the-owner-of-a-process-in-c)

```
public string GetProcessOwner(int processId) 
{ 
    string query = "Select * From Win32_Process Where ProcessID = " + processId; 
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query); 
    ManagementObjectCollection processList = searcher.Get(); 

    foreach (ManagementObject obj in processList) 
    { 
        string[] argList = new string[] { string.Empty, string.Empty }; 
        int returnVal = Convert.ToInt32(obj.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", argList)); 
        if (returnVal == 0) 
        { 
            // return DOMAIN\user 
            return argList[1] + "\\" + argList[0]; 
        } 
    } 

    return "NO OWNER"; 
}
```