# Who connected remotely?

Tags: c#, remote-access

We have ten user-names for the software and due to licensing issues, we need 10 separate machines (10 different IPs). Multiple users can remotely access a machine at the same time, but only one user can be using this program on the machine.
Okay, so here is the deal. I am developing a simple application in c# Visual that shows whether an instance of a program is currently running on the machines (a simple table). It works well.
I thought of adding to the table a column 'owner' - who is running the instance of the program on a particular machine. Can I somehow track the IP of the person who remotely logged in and started the process? There is only one account on each machine.

Thanks.

Comment: See this related question: > [**How do I determine the owner of a process in C#?**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/777567/40347)

Comment: The thing is, though, that I need the IP in order to track back the person who is remotely connected.

Comment: Are the users connected using RDP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to display the owner of the respective process, i.e. the user name that can be seen e.g. using Task Manager or Process Explorer.

One option to retrieve the owner of a process it to use WMI. This is e.g. decribed in this related question:

> [**How do I determine the owner of a process in C#?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/777567/40347)

If you additionally want to retrieve the user in an RDP session you might want to have a look at the [Cassia](http://code.google.com/p/cassia/) library, e.g. using code like the following:

```
new TerminalServicesManager().CurrentSession.ClientName
```

to get the client's host name, or

```
new TerminalServicesManager().CurrentSession.UserName
```

to get the user name.

Comment: Hey, are you very familiar with the Cassia library? I am running into some problems...