# VB.Net 2.0 Windows Forms - How do I get the executing User

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-2.0

I have a .Net 2.0 Windows Forms application which needs to be run as a specific user (right click, run as).

I need to be able to check which user has launched it and stop if it is not the specific user.

All the examples I have found show the logged in user.

How can I access the application executing username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/siva/archive/2006/10/02/Getting-Windows-Process-Owner-Name.aspx), with a little bit of help from [this](http://www.pinvoke.net/), I came up with this:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Security.Principal

Public Class GetProcessOwner

    <DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function OpenProcessToken(ByVal processHandle As IntPtr, ByVal desiredAccess As Integer, ByRef tokenHandle As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function CloseHandle(ByVal hObject As IntPtr) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    End Function

    Private Const TokenQuery As UInteger = &H8

    Public Shared Function GetProcessOwner(ByVal processName As String) As String

        Dim ownerName As String = String.Empty

        For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses()

            If p.ProcessName = processName Then

                Dim ph As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero

                Try
                    OpenProcessToken(p.Handle, TokenQuery, ph)
                    Dim wi As WindowsIdentity = New WindowsIdentity(ph)
                    ownerName = wi.Name

                Catch ex As Exception

                    ownerName = String.Empty

                Finally

                    If ph <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                        CloseHandle(ph)
                    End If

                End Try

            End If

        Next

        Return ownerName

    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help you: [How do I determine the owner of a process in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777548/how-do-i-determine-the-owner-of-a-process-in-c)

It's in C# but that's easily converted to VB.NET, just search Google for "C# to VB" :)