# How to identify the user from windows service?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have developed a windows service that sends a mail automatically when the Windows User logs in. Now I want to add the User's name in the body of that mail. How can I identify the user, using windows service? Is it possible? Please tell me about some properties allowed in Windows service (C#) which can identify the user's name.

Comment: How have you solved the first problem? (understand when a new user logs in?) Knowing the mechanism, will be easier to understand how to proceed..

Answer (score 0):

The current user logged on to the system can be extracted as follows:

```
string user = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

Here is the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sfs49sw0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score -2):

you can easily get the current user name when you try the following statement:

```
System.Environment.UserName.ToString();
```

There are also some other members of the Environment class you can use, see: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: This statement returns the user of the current process. If the user of some other process is required, the following discussion could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777548/how-do-i-determine-the-owner-of-a-process-in-c

Comment: Oops, didn't notice that the OP was talking about a service. 
That will probably return System or Administrator when using Environment.UserName