# How to find an C# Application Running under Username "System" or not

Tags: c#

I searched quite a few answers in StackOverflow but can't make it work.

This is my code:

```
bool Active = Process.GetProcessesByName("EXENAME").Any();
```

as you can see 'ACTIVE' gets true when the process "EXENAME" is running, but I want it more precise, I want to keep it in False state if the process "EXENAME" is running under System as well.

Please help!

Comment: Perhaps this will help you. This is a tip using WMI http://stackoverflow.com/a/777567/3877877

Comment: Unrelated, but your can simplify your code (and make it far more clear) by changing `.FirstOrDefault(...) != default(Process)` to `.Any(...)`

Comment: @Rob I Simplified it :) Thanks for the advice

Comment: @Mike No worries - but you still need the predicate inside `Any()` :). It should be: `.Any(p => p.MainModule.FileName.StartsWith(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir")))` to keep the same logic you had before

Comment: @Rob That's cool, don't need to check the path anymore, the only issue is to figure out the owner is "system" or not :(

Comment: @Slai Where should I put that Mate?