# Process.StartInfo.Username is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, process

I start a Process by

```
Process app = new Process();
app.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
app.StartInfo.FileName = path;
app.StartInfo.Domain = "Domain";
app.StartInfo.UserName = "userName";

string password = "Password";
System.Security.SecureString ssPwd = new System.Security.SecureString();

for (int x = 0; x < password.Length; x++)
{
    ssPwd.AppendChar(password[x]);
}

password = "";

app.StartInfo.Password = ssPwd;
app.Start();
```

Then I confirm it is running by:

```
private bool IsRunning(string name)
{
    Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

    if (Process.GetProcessesByName(name).Length > 0)
    {
        string user = Process.GetProcessesByName(name)[0].StartInfo.UserName; 
        log.Debug("Process " + name + " is running by : " + user);

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I get back `true` and find the process but the `UserName` is empty. 
Why is that?

I also found some code to get the Owner of the Process but when I use this the Owner is also empty.

```
public string GetProcessOwner(int processId)
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessID = " + processId;
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
    ManagementObjectCollection processList = searcher.Get();

    foreach (ManagementObject obj in processList)
    {
        string[] argList = new string[] { string.Empty, string.Empty };
        int returnVal = Convert.ToInt32(obj.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", argList));

        if (returnVal == 0)
        {
            // return DOMAIN\user
            return argList[1] + "\\" + argList[0];
        }
    }

    return "NO OWNER";
}
```

Please can you explain me why this is so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is by design; when requesting information about a `Process` via eg. `GetProcessesByName` the `UserName` doesn't get retrieved/resolved.

[`GetProcessByName`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,1145259cd5d3303b) internally retrieves its info via [the code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,87ff4550e7d5526b) below, constructing `Process` instances from the obtained `ProcesInfo` data.

```
  public static Process[] GetProcesses(string machineName) 
  {
        bool isRemoteMachine = ProcessManager.IsRemoteMachine(machineName);
        ProcessInfo[] processInfos = ProcessManager.GetProcessInfos(machineName);
        Process[] processes = new Process[processInfos.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < processInfos.Length; i++) {
            ProcessInfo processInfo = processInfos[i];

            processes[i] = new Process(machineName, isRemoteMachine, processInfo.processId, processInfo);
        }

        return processes;
}
```

A [`ProcessInfo`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,fcd5be3e64076ea7) instance doesn't contain any user/owner information.

```
internal class ProcessInfo 
{
    public ArrayList threadInfoList = new ArrayList();
    public int basePriority;
    public string processName;
    public int processId;
    public int handleCount;
    public long poolPagedBytes;
    public long poolNonpagedBytes;
    public long virtualBytes;
    public long virtualBytesPeak;
    public long workingSetPeak;
    public long workingSet;
    public long pageFileBytesPeak;
    public long pageFileBytes;
    public long privateBytes;
    public int mainModuleId;
    public int sessionId;
}
```

The [private constructor](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,158) of the `Process` class accepts this `ProcessInfo`.

Because no `ProcessStartInfo` has been set, it [instantiates one](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,977) on retrieval, having an [empty `UserName`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/ProcessStartInfo.cs,324).

```
public string UserName {
    get { 
        if( userName == null) {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        else {        
            return userName;                     
        }
    } 
    set { userName = value; }
}
```

---

About the `GetProcessOwner` code; this results from the answer to the [How do I determine the owner of a process in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777548/how-do-i-determine-the-owner-of-a-process-in-c) question.

This is rather an other `WMI` related topic; not receiving any owner info might have to do with permissions as suggested in the comments.
For me, "it works on my machine" ...
Better start a separate question for this one.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with solution using WinAPIs

You would get `"NO OWNER"` when the application you are trying to get the owner, is not run as admin
Please check by running your application as Administrator