# How to get logged in user in windows server using C# when "Application owner" is admin and not a logged in user?

Tags: c#, windows-server-2012-r2

I am writing an application that will run on windows server.
The scenario is that user will login using normal domain account and application will run using administrator account.
**I need to get the user currently logged in to windows to do some processing.**

when I get user name using following method i**t gives me the admin account used to run the exe and not the account logged in to windows current session.**

```cs
string username = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

Then I tried following method to get the logged in user

```cs
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();

string username = (string)collection.Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().First()["UserName"];
```

This code is working fine on windows 10 and giving me the user currently logged in to windows. But on windows server 2012 it is returning empty string.

How can I get the logged in user when running the exe on windows server??
I dont want to know how many sessions are running on windows server. i want to know the current logged in user.

Comment: Absent any smarter solution, perhaps an exe you start normally can get the username, and then start your main app as an administrator, passing the normal username as a command line arg.. alternatively, your wmi approach but get the name of a process that runs under that user when the user logs on, such as explorer.. tight now you're just picking the first process blindly. Though remember that in a server context especially there may be multiple logged in users at the same time - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777548/how-do-i-determine-the-owner-of-a-process-in-c

Comment: Also review the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240373/how-do-i-get-the-current-username-in-net-using-c - if none of them work, you show you've tried them

Answer (score -1):

In Windows, current logged-on user is written to environment variable `USERNAME`, his domain - to `USERDOMAIN`, and you can read this values with [System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable)

You can list all (currently set) environment variables with `set` command in console/command prompt.

Comment: I suspect that this will also return the admin account used to run the exe, not the name of the logged on user