# Check the process owner name before killing process in Node JS

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, process, node-modules

Does any Node library provide an option to get the owner's name? This is to avoid killing the processes of users in the case of a multiuser system.

Using the below code snippet to kill processes.

```
                    const find = require('find-process');

                    find('name', 'Teams', true).then(function (list) {
                    var i;
                    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                        //logger.info(list[i].pid);
                        process.kill(list[i].pid);

                      }
                    });
```

Does it ensure to return processes of the current user or check username check is required before killing it?

How can the process owner's name be obtained? (As in [Similar to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777548/how-do-i-determine-the-owner-of-a-process-in-c) )

Added on: 3rd August 2021.

Now I see that there are some packages available but restricted to certain OS versions.
In this case, I am looking for some way in Windows 10.

1. Owner name and/or uid of the logged-in user and process
2. Owner name and/or uid of the process to be killed (Whichever the package which returns the required details for the process list)

Comment: Seems a cloud server which runs a multiuser system gave each user a configuration. So there would be an answer at the cloud server website?

Comment: @jacobkim, No Idea. Please can you point me to it?

Comment: Not sure either. Does the node server run on a cloud computer?

Comment: It will be used in Desktop App (Node.exe will be present locally.)

Comment: Do you want to get the process by the root user or any other user?

Comment: No. Just want to compare if the process being killed is owned by the current user.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to get the list of process running on the system. For that you can use this node package [ps-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ps-list).

To get the list you can write this code:

```
const psList = require('ps-list');
(async () => {
    console.log(await psList());
    //=> [{pid: 3213, name: 'node', cmd: 'node test.js', ppid: 1, uid: 501, cpu: 0.1, memory: 1.5}, …]
})();
```

Once you do get that you can get the `uids` from the process list and then match it with the current user running the node process from where you are executing.
To get the `uid` of the user currently running the node process, you can write this:

```
const os=require("os");
const userInfo=os.userInfo();
console.log(userInfo.uid);
```

Once you get the process that match the uid with the current user you can kill those process with this [code](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_kill_pid_signal).

Comment: Ps-List code doesn't seem to be working in the window and throws an error. Also, userInfo always returns -1 as uid.